# Gingko Tree leaves yellowing/greying falling in June

Tags: trees, leaves, tree-care

This beautiful Gingko tree leaves are starting to yellow and fall and it’s barely July! The leaves seem to have a uniform yellowing, almost grey tint and are starting to fall off.

The tree is about 8ft tall, planted spring before last. Unfortunately, this spring we did have to transplant the tree a few feet to its current location (for easement code). We did this while the tree was dormant in late winter and she did fill in with beautiful leaves.

We are located in zone 5b. Recently the summer temperatures have gotten warmer (80°F). And we’ve started watering the lawn every other day. We’ve also given some deep water to the tree. The only other thing I can think of is a standard brand fertilizer for the lawn.

Too much water? Not enough? What’s going on?

[image]

Comment: 1 month update: a wind storm took most of the yellow week leavers. I dug a hole adjacent to the tree and I suspect that the tree was water logged as water seeped into the new hole. The soil around the tree is very compact, clay-like, and does not drain water well, but the soil the tree came planted in is very soft and permeable. I suspect it just held water like a bucket and the tree became water logged.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the roots have been damaged.  I would wait a few more months, but keep watering it (not water-logged though)

> The tree has an angular crown and long, somewhat erratic branches, and is usually **deep-rooted** and resistant to wind and snow damage

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ginkgo_biloba)

Here's an image of the [roots](https://kwanten.home.xs4all.nl/roots.htm)

[image]

I am not associated with either site